# Strange thin line or dots at the bottom of my opengl texture

Tags: objective-c, opengl-es, textures, texture-mapping

I have made an app similar to this one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U2uH-jrsSxs (the sound is a bit loud and bad). The problem is there is a very thin line/dots/whatever appearing at the bottom of every texture. It is almost unnoticeable but it is there and I have no idea why. My texture size is 256x256. I tested earliear with a texture size 128x128 I THINK there was nothing there but not sure. It's not such a big deal as it is very thin but I find it annoying. Here is a [screenshot](http://img545.imageshack.us/i/screenshot2011030110052.jpg/). I have selected with RED those lines. I'm a noob at OpenGL(ES) so probably I did something wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will be due to OpenGL tiling the texture to fill the specified area. So the thin line you are seeing will be the very top of that texture just starting to repeat again.

To avoid it, tell the texture to CLAMP, rather than REPEAT (repeat being synonymous with tiling). Textures repeat by default, so you will want a line something like this:

```
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP );
    glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP );
```

If you're this way inclined, there is also a no-code-involved bodge way around it. Simply edit your source graphics so that no pixels are present in the top or left edges. So move the whole lot down one pixel and right one pixel inside its canvas. But then of course you will need to adjust your coordinates if you want the images to appear in exactly the same place.

Comment: Ah, yes that was the problem! BTW `GL_CLAMP` was not recognized but `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE` was ok. I assume it's because it's openglES. I didn't think I need to specify the texture wrapping/repeating parameter if I'm not actually repeating my textures at all. Thanks.